# Why Won't Asynchronous SOAP Web Services Calls Work

Tags: cocoa, nsrunloop

I used WSMakeStubs (in the dev tools) to generate stub code for accessing a SOAP web service. The calls I make to the object just block currently. When I try to use the async calls, nothing happens and I'm sure it has to do with my understanding of run loops. I initialize an object and try to schedule it on a run loop like this:

```
BeginPartnerSession *call = [[BeginPartnerSession alloc] init];
[call setParameters:kPartnerID in_Password:kPartnerPassword];
[call setCallBack:self selector:@selector(sessionIDRequestDidFinish:)];
[call scheduleOnRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] mode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[call release];
```

The stub call for scheduling on the run loop looks like this:

```
- (void) scheduleOnRunLoop:(NSRunLoop*) runloop mode:(NSString*) mode
{
  WSMethodInvocationScheduleWithRunLoop([self getRef], [runloop getCFRunLoop], (CFStringRef) mode);
}
```

The call to [self getRef] returns an invocation object that has set the callback. The callback is then supposed to call out to my target and selector, but it never hits that break point after calling schedule with run loop. What needs to change in the run loop scheduling to get it to work correctly?

Synchronous calls work fine, so I'm pretty sure it's not a server issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally broke this out into a separate project where I could isolate the problem. The async call worked just fine there which made the runloop suspect to me. Turns out the issue had to do with the fact that I am running this as a plugin for iPhoto. I simply changed the runloop mode so the call looked like this:

```
[call scheduleOnRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] mode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Then the callback got called. Voila!